# Define an abstract method without specifying parameters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstract-class

I am writing an abstract class with an abstract method (thus, all classes inheriting from it must implement that method). However, I do not want to specify the parameters which the method must use, as each method may take in different or no parameters. Only the name and return value should be the same.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, and it would be pointless to do so. If you didn't declare the parameters, you wouldn't be able to call the method given only a reference to the base class. That's the point of abstract methods: to allow callers not to care about the concrete implementation, but to give them an API to use.

If the caller needs to know the exact method signature then you've tied that caller to a concrete implementation, making the abstraction essentially useless.

Perhaps if you could give more details, we could suggest a more appropriate approach? For example, you might be able to make the type generic:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public abstract void Bar(T t);
}
```

Concrete subtypes could either *also* be generic, or derive from `Foo<string>` for example.

Comment: Each child must create an implementation of this method where it can take in different types of input, but will produce the same type of output. Thus I can use the output to perform the logic of my program.

Comment: @TheBoss: The point of abstract classes (like interfaces) is to allow for an..well..abstraction of common functionality. You can't use it to define something like "You need a function called `Foo` that takes *some* (or no) parameters and returns an `int`"; such a function can't be abstracted, since its signature is undefined. It would be impossible to call (non-reflectively) from code that references the class at a higher level than where the specific signature is defined, breaking the abstraction.

Comment: @TheBoss: I think you should look into using Generics to solve your design challenge - like the code example that Jon posted.

Comment: The problem is that generics can be used if you know the number of unknown arguments which are used, but in my case the number of arguments may vary.

Comment: @TheBoss: Then it's not appropriate for this particular case - but neither is inheritance in general...

Comment: @JonSkeet given the reasoning behind your answer, abstract class concept exact to interfaces (apart defined parameters & allowing multi-implementation of interfaces which comes with a *cost* of having to implement all methods in an interface; where as abstract class allows the *freedom* to *choose* and override) But is that really the case? Without a signature, abstract method looks as ***body-less*** as an interface method to me. [But this says otherwise.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w2ctx1s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Keep me wondering if abstract classes are all we need?

Answer (score 4):

No. Why do you need it? maybe the [Command Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) can help here.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is a code smell.

A better pattern would be to have your abstract class implement [ISupportInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx), and then have an abstract `Act()` method.

The idea is that in between calls to `BeginInit` and `EndInit` is when your child types prepare to act, gathering the different bits of info you are trying to cram into random types and numbers of arguments.  Once configured, and `EndInit` is called (validate here) the abstract `Act()` can be called.

Also, please PLEASE do not do this:

```
public abstract void Act(params object[] arguments);
```

People will hunt you down if you do something like this.

Comment: That is an interesting approach. So I would have a boolean field in the class which would indicate when the initialisation has completed, and only then would the Act() method successfully execute otherwise it would throw an exception?

Comment: @TheBoss the standard technique is to verify the state of the instance on EndInit and throw if it is not in a correct state.  Types that implement this interface often make themselves immutable after a call to EndInit.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

To override a method, you must match the method signature. This includes the method name and format parameters.

Answer (score -1):

This question needed some more examples of what do do here, so here's one. My specific scenario is I get the concrete instance of an abstract `ActionBaseClass` from a factory and I need to call some `DoAction()` function on that instance with parameters specific to my scenario.

Here's the definitions of the classes:

```
public abstract class ActionsClassBase
{
    // Hint for the funciton we want on our concrete instances
    public virtual bool DoAction() =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class MyConcreteInstance : ActionsClassBase
{
    public bool DoAction(object a, string b, int c)
    {
        // your implmentation
    }
}
```

Observe how `MyConcreteInstance.DoAction()` has the parameters it needs for the specific scenario.  Note that this funcion doesn't implement/override `ActionsBaseClass.DoAction`, which in this case is just a hint to the developer of the name of the function it wants the concrete types to implement.

I get my instance from the factory like this:

```
var myA = somethingA;
var myB = somethingB;
var myC = somethingC;

// `SomeFactory.Create` returns the instance as `ActionsClassBase`
var myAction = SomeFactory.Create(typeof(MyConcreteInstance)) as MyConcreteInstance;
```

I'm casting to my concrete instance's type because in this scenario I know what it's supposed to be, and I have values for the parameters I need to call `DoAction` on it (`myA`, `myB`, and `myC`).  We need some object that will hold these parameters and pass them into the action on the concrete instance.

The trick here is to create a resolver object that will do the work for us.  We create an abstract resolver for all our concrete instances to use, and a specific resolver for our specific class:

```
public abstract class DoActionResolver
{
    // Function with the same parameters and return type as in `AbstractClassBase`
    public abstract bool DoAction();
}

public class MyConcreteInstanceDoActionResolver : DoActionResolver
{
    MyConcreteInstance _instance;
    object _a;
    string _b;
    int _c;

    public MyConcreteInstanceDoActionResolver(MyConcreteInstance instance, object a, string b, int c)
    {
        _instance = instance
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }

    public override bool DoAction() =>
        _instance.DoAction(_a, _b, _c);
}
```

Now I can create an instance of my resolver on which I can call `DoAction` with the parameters I need:

```
// I already know what I need to call the action with on my instance in this scenario.
// Lets assume we are storing them in variables with names myA, myB, and myC
var myActionResolver = new MyConcreteInstaceDoActionResolver(myAction, myA, myB, myC);
```

Finally, I can call the action through my resolver:

```
myActionResolver.DoAction();
```